# Flexslider and Jquery UI conflict

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, conflict, flexslider

Have flexslider with thumbs:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  // The slider being synced must be initialized first
  $('#carousel').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    itemWidth: 210,
    itemMargin: 5,
    asNavFor: '#slider'
  });

  $('#slider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    sync: "#carousel"
  });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/raskalbass/83PaB/)

All works greatly. But if I include jquery UI - slider not working.

[DEMO with UI](http://jsfiddle.net/raskalbass/83PaB/1/)

How could I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `jquery` and `jquery ui` versions. Use jquery.2x(edge) and jquery ui 1.10.3 in jsfiddle.

This is working here: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/83PaB/2/